# When is the address indicated on a passport being used?

Tags: passports, french-citizens

My French passport indicates my physical address. What's the point of it? I.e., when is the address indicated on a passport being used?

[image]

([image source](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/images/196079.jpg), sorry I couldn't find any specimen with a higher definition)

Comment: The residence information contained in the [French passport Biodata page](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/FRA-AO-03003/image-196079.html) in not a mandatory entry for passports. Since most other passports don't have such an entry, it is probably not used at all for international travel.

Comment: When you move house, or even countries, you do not have to update your passport (as far as I understand.) That would mean to me that the address will not be up to date for many people and thus useless.

Comment: Once, in my case, I had written my Dutch address in my US passport. That caused a Belgian border guard to get very upset with met, apparently thinking I was in the Netherlands illegally. How he missed my giant residency permit in the passport I don't know, but I showed it to him and he went off in a huff.

Comment: Canadian passports have a place for your 'permanent address' on the Loss and Theft page, I've seldom filled it out.

Comment: I had a hotel deny me lodging because my only photo ID on hand was my passport, and my country doesn't put an address on there (Much for the same reason mentioned by Willeke, it's not a reliable value), and they required an id to have an address. Luckily I had made the reservation through a 3rd party company who I called, and they said that address requirement was unreasonable, and they refunded me the cost of that hotel and put me up in another location free of charge. Not having an address there saved me the cost of two nights lodging, go figure ;)

Comment: I was really worried about that passport image until I looked a little closer and saw it was issued to `Specimen, Natacha`. Whew!

Comment: @FreeMan tough to get some privacy when one's last name is Specimen ;)

Comment: I notice that the French national ID card also shows the address.  Perhaps the address is simply thought to be one of the things that ought to be included in an identification document, or perhaps it is even specified in French law.

Answer (score 15):

In theory, if you lose your passport and someone finds it, they could mail it to your address.  Alternatively, if you have some sort of incapacitating emergency, somebody could contact you at the address.  Here's an Australian passport's address page which makes this explicit:

[image]

**In practice, this never happens.** If you lose your passport while travelling, you need to make a police report and tell your embassy, who will electronically invalidate it as part of the process of issuing a new one.  So there's no point to mailing around found passports.  Likewise, if you have an emergency, your emergency contact will be contacted by phone, not by sending a letter.

This has not gone unnoticed, and addresses on passports are an endangered species these days: having an address in the passport is not mandated by [ICAO regulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport), and most countries' passports no longer have it.

Comment: So what theory is that ?

Comment: The theory that somebody could mail the passport to the address written on it.

Comment: This is speculation.

Comment: @phoog Added another useless rationale and a scan of an Australian passport that verified it.  If you have better ideas or sources, post 'em up!

Answer (score 3):

Since the introduction of the 'International' Passport in the 1920's, passports should have a **Domicile** entry (Page 2 of sample passport, Annex 1 of 1920 Conference, page 156 of pdf).

[image: Annex I of 1920 Passport Conference]

The recommendations do not state the purpose or what this field should contain.

However since the general agreement about the issuing of visas states, as a general rule, that visas should be issued at **the place of domicile of the applicant** (a rule which still applies today), this is probably the reason for this field.

In German passports (former and present), only the **city** is entered on the *Biographical data* page.

---

> **FINAL ACT**
> adopted by the Passport Conference on May 18th, 1926.
> ...
> RECOMMENDATIONS
> SECTION I. - GENERAL QUESTIONS.
> II . Facilities to be Granted.
> ...
> B. Visas.
> The Conference recommends:
> ...
> (3) That, although as a general rule visas are granted by the diplomatic or consular authorities competent **for the place of domicile of the applicant**, the diplomatic and consular authorities may in cases deserving special consideration grant visas to persons not domiciled in their area and that as far as possible the said authorities shall not require the applicant to appear in person. In the case of transit visas, the applicant should only be required to appear in person if the authority granting the visas has doubts regarding the case.

---

[image]

---

**Sources**:

- [1926-05-18: Geneva Passport Conference](https://biblio-archive.unog.ch/Dateien/CouncilMSD/C-423-M-156-1926-VIII_EN.pdf) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/1926-05-18-geneva-passport-conference))
- [1928: Hall’s Passport « Hall's Journals](http://halllippincott.com/?page_id=2755)

Comment: Interesting - I'm trying to find something similar in my passport.  I have "Nationality" and "Place of Birth", but not "Domicile".  I would have [defined "Domicile"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/domicile) as place of residence (whether that's country or city I guess is up to further interpretation), but my passport lists neither of those.  I have a New Zealand passport but I live in Mexico.

Comment: @Midavalo Many countries did not follow the recommendations in full. A 1928 US Passport did not have a field on the description page, although the inside page has room for a private entry of address as well as a notification address.

Comment: Thanks, interesting! Follow-up question: [In what case(s) is a visa only issued at the place of domicile of the applicant?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158173/1810)

Comment: This answer is pure speculation.  (Also, US passports to this day have a place for the bearer to pencil in an address.  "Pencil," because addresses may change.  But nothing in this answer indicates that this is contrary to any recommendation.)

Comment: @phoog Note that the word **probably** was used. It was **not** stated as a fact, but a logical conclusion based on the fact that the **domicile** field verifies this when required for a visa application. The pdf documents this. Just because you fail to comprehend this, does not mean it is speculation. Stop acting holier than the pope. Your downvote is, yet again, unjustified.

Comment: @phoog For your convenience, I have added a link to the meantioned type III passport (1926-28) page. There you can convince yourself that a) a statement that a pencil should be used (that you state as a **fact** and not as advice) is not meantioned b) that ink was used. A 1967 passport even state that that entry may be altered. Since the OP question did not address the question as to whether it fullfills the recommendation, it was not part of the answer, but only in the comment showing that countries implemented the recommendations differently.

Comment: @MarkJohnson on what basis are you claiming the 1926 conference makes a recommendation for a "domicile" field? The section you've quoted certainly says no such thing.

Comment: @ChrisH Based on the entry on page 2 of the sample passport (page 156 of the pdf). Annex I of the 1920 conference.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the "pencil" comment was based on today's passports, not those of the 1920s.  The recommendation to use pencil has been present at least since the 1970s if my memory serves me correctly.  Anyway, I've removed my downvote.  Thank you for linking to "Hall's passport" -- it's fascinating.

Comment: @phoog The Journals are also interesting to read. His main problem was with Customs. He bought a bicycle in England and used it throughout Europe. At every border he had to pay a customs fee for the bicycle that was supposed to be refunded when leaving. He lost the bicycle on the Spanish/Portuguese border since the Spanish refused the refund and he couldn't afford the Portuguese fee.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked the question to an employee at the [French Embassy in Bangkok](https://goo.gl/maps/cWUww2jgoWiPkdJM8) working on issuing new passports does accept: she couldn't think of any use of the address indicated on a French passport. So it's unlikely that the address indicated on a French passport has any major role, if any. lambshaanxy's answer gives the best reason I can think of, and Mark Johnson's answer seems to explain well the origin of this relic of the past.

Also, according to https://passeport.ants.gouv.fr/Questions-frequentes/Questions-pratiques/Je-demenage-dois-je-modifier-mon-passeport-ma-carte-nationale-d-identite ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200715045145/https://passeport.ants.gouv.fr/Questions-frequentes/Questions-pratiques/Je-demenage-dois-je-modifier-mon-passeport-ma-carte-nationale-d-identite)):

> Si vous déménagez, le changement de l'adresse portée sur le passeport, la carte d'identité ou le permis de conduire est facultatif.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Si%20vous%20d%C3%A9m%C3%A9nagez%2C%20le%20changement%20de%20l%27adresse%20port%C3%A9e%20sur%20le%20passeport%2C%20la%20carte%20d%27identit%C3%A9%20ou%20le%20permis%20de%20conduire%20est%20facultatif.):

> If you move, changing the address on your passport, identity card or driver's license is optional.

Comment: It would seem that a full address was common place for French passports. Image: [French Passport, 1939 with full address](http://ourpassports.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1-7-1024x716.png)

Comment: Franck Dernoncourt: How does one actually change the address?  Do they issue a new document or add some note to the existing one?  In New York, licensed drivers must report a change of address to the Department of Motor Vehicles within 10 days, but getting a new license is optional; one may instead write the new address on the document in a space provided for this purpose on the back.  (This is actually very difficult to do because ink tends not to stick to the polycarbonate.)