# In what case(s) is a visa only issued at the place of domicile of the applicant?

Tags: visas, international-travel, french-citizens

I read on [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158128/1810) by [Mark Johnson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/95267/mark-johnson):

> [Since] the general agreement about the issuing of visas states,
> as a general rule, that visas should be issued at **the place of
> domicile of the applicant** (a rule which still applies today), this
> is probably the reason for this [physical address] field [on some passports].
>
> [...]
>
> ---
>
> > **FINAL ACT**   adopted by the Passport Conference on May 18th, 1926.
> > ...
> > RECOMMENDATIONS
> > SECTION I. - GENERAL QUESTIONS.
> > II . Facilities to be Granted.
> > ...
> > B. Visas.    The Conference recommends:
> > ...
> > (3) That, although as a general rule visas are granted by the diplomatic or consular authorities competent **for the place of
> > domicile of the applicant**, the diplomatic and consular authorities
> > may in cases deserving special consideration grant visas to persons
> > not domiciled in their area and that as far as possible the said
> > authorities shall not require the applicant to appear in person. In
> > the case of transit visas, the applicant should only be required to
> > appear in person if the authority granting the visas has doubts
> > regarding the case.
>
> ---
>
> **Sources**:
>
> - [1926-05-18: Geneva Passport Conference](https://biblio-archive.unog.ch/Dateien/CouncilMSD/C-423-M-156-1926-VIII_EN.pdf) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/1926-05-18-geneva-passport-conference))

In what case(s) is a visa only issued at the place of domicile of the applicant? Or is this II.B.(3) rule dating back from 1926 in practice just ignored by all nowadays?

In practice I have never seen a visa only issued at the place of domicile of the applicant. E.g. as a French citizen domiciled in California with a French address on my French passport, [I can obtain a Chinese visa in Hong Kong](https://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/visa-application/in-hong-kong.htm) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/4ieHz)).

If specific to the applicant's citizenship, I am interested in French citizens (possibly with a US double citizenship) applying for visas.

Comment: Ironically, France does in general require people to apply for a visa at the consulate serving their place of usual residence. As a French citizen, that doesn't impact you of course. Ultimately, the passport conference doesn't carry much weight, it's up to each country.

Comment: @Relaxed interesting, I thought that France was "only" forcing Chinese citizens (I don't know about other citizens. I know for China because they understandingly reciprocate that stupid rule.) to come in person at the French embassy, but not necessarily at the French embassy/consulate that is the nearest to their domicile.

Comment: @chx Good news I've just  edited to make much more focused.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/148256/30703

Comment: Note that "domicile" is nowadays usually a much more specific thing than residence. Most countries restricting delivery of visas to the consulate/embassy serving the place of residence use the notion of residence, not domicile. Domicile is (or was?) a notion for UK tax which meant a very long-term attachment to a country (i.e. living there for over 10 years).

Comment: @jcaron the concept of "domicile" is by no means exclusive to UK tax law.

Comment: @jcaron (e.g. [Is an individual who hasn't been in California in 2019 but is domiciled in California throughout 2019 a California tax resident?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/126904/5656))

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it's not the consulate "nearest to their domicile" but rather *in whose jurisdiction they reside.*  The two are not always the same.  This rule is imposed by the Schengen Visa Code, so it applies to all Schengen visa applicants.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, does the Schengen Visa Code define "in whose jurisdiction they reside."? I.e., what is regarded as a residence?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt no.  But it doesn't affect you anyway because you are French.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, if "reside" isn't defined, in practice do the consulate employees even check for that? (yes luckily I dodged this bullet by being born on the old continent...)

Comment: One issue is that consular staff are familiar with local applications. If a resident of India applies for a visa in India, the consulate knows what's normal locally, knows what common documents look like, and will have local national staff who know how to verify details. If an Indian resident applies for a visa in Panama, they're suddenly asking staff to start working in rupees and figure out how to verify someone's employment on the other side of the world. So some countries either prefer you apply where you reside (and may be more likely to deny a visa otherwise) or strictly require it.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The point was that for a given point of residence (however defined), there is one consulate in charge and it can occasionally be further away than the nearest consulate. One common example is living near an international border as consular districts often follow those.

Comment: @ZachLipton Indeed! A third model is to allow applications anywhere but forward them (presumably electronically) to be processed at the consulate serving the place of usual residence. I think Canada was doing this.

Comment: @ZachLipton I believe your comment is the nearest one will get to a realistic answer to this question. The more inquisitive a consulate is a about the applicant (salary, bank statements, travel record) the more likely it is that the application must be made near his place of residence. In the 1970 and 80s, Czechoslovakia, Hungry and Poland issued their tourist visas mostly within a 24/48 hour period from almost any consulate making a casual visit possible for someone visiting a nearby country.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I am sure that each consulate has a working definition of "reside"; the point is that the definition is not established by the Schengen Visa Code.  It might be established by the country or it might be left to each consulate to decide.  The point is that they are supposed to establish that the applicant resides in their territory, and yes, they do check.

Comment: @Relaxed indeed.  In the US, consular districts typically follow state borders, or in some cases county borders.  It is easy to find examples when one considers the French consular districts: Pennsylvania is in the Washington DC consular district, but the eastern part of the state is closer to New York; Connecticut is part of the New York district, but the northeastern part is closer to Boston; North Carolina is in the Atlanta district, but much of it is closer to Washington.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a rule, it's a recommendation.  Some countries follow it (for example the Schengen countries) while others don't (for example the US, the UK, and apparently China).

Comment: Glad I typically don't need visas for Schengen countries :-/ Surprised that China doesn't reciprocate that.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt people seem to think that visa rules are based on some sort of reciprocal agreement, but they often aren't.  In particular, rules governing whether applications must be submitted to a particular consulate don't typically depend on the nationality of the applicant.

Comment: The visa application process does depend on the nationality of the applicant in the case of French citizens applying to a Chinese visa in the US (perhaps worldwide, idk) :( No reciprocal agreement, just Chinese mirroring some stupid French visa process rule.